# Generate a UTF-8 character from two HEX pairs

Tags: perl, utf-8

I am trying to generate a UTF-8 character from 2 HEX pairs. The HEX pairs are from strings.

This code works:

```
use Encode;

my $bytes = "\xC3\xA9";
print decode_utf8($bytes);

# Prints: é and is correct
```

This code does not work:

```
use Encode;

my $byte1 = "C3";
my $byte2 = "A9";
my $bytes = "\x$byte1\x$byte2";
print decode_utf8($bytes);
```

Here is the character that I am trying to generate: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e9/index.htm

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Encode;

my $byte1 = "C3";
my $byte2 = "A9";
my $bytes = chr(hex($byte1)) . chr(hex($byte2));
print decode_utf8($bytes);
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly! I appreciate the assistance. The answer by ikegami helped me understand what is happening with the hex values.

Answer (score 3):

Think of string literals as a mini language. You can't do

```
"\x$hex"
```

any more than you can do

```
my $for = 'for';
$for (1..4) { }
```

But there are plenty of ways to do what you want.

```
my $bytes = join '', map chr hex, @bytes_hex;
my $bytes = pack 'C*', map hex, @bytes_hex;
my $bytes = pack '(H*)*', @bytes_hex;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The "\xCA" part made me think it was a string, since 0xCA is not quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Aahh ysth beat me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode;
use utf8::all;

my $byte1 = "C3";
my $byte2 = "A9";
my $bytes = join '', map {chr hex} $byte1, $byte2;

print decode_utf8($bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well. It is also valid.